# When returning pointers, when does data need to be static?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, static

I noticed something that I'd like an answer to regarding pointers and variables, it's not really a problem but I'd like to understand the details. To put it simply, to bypass using global variables, I've been starting to have functions return pointers to the data inside the function. And sometimes, that data needs to be static, other times it doesn't.

For example, let's say I have a function that creates a 2d char array, populates it with 'a' and returns a pointer pointing to that array. When the caller tries to use that pointer to access and modify the memory where the 2d array was, random data is there instead of the 2d array's contents. I found out that declaring the 2d array as static fixes this, because the array's contents are saved outside of its scope.

Now on the other hand, let's say I have a function that declares a struct, and initializes it with values. The function then returns a pointer to that struct variable. The caller should have nonsense data when trying to access the struct's values through the pointer but interestingly, it doesn't. I would think that like in the case of the 2d array, after the function call, since the struct is not static, the data at that memory should be freed. However, it's not like that, instead I can access all the struct's elements through the pointer despite it not being static.

Overall, after a function is finished, the caller can access and modify the data of variables created in that function as long as that data was static (in the 2d array case) but sometimes the data of variables is retained outside of scope despite not being labeled static (struct case). Why?

Comment: Officially, local variables cease to exist as soon as the function returns. In practice, sometimes the data persists for a longer period of time. `static` variables, on the other hand, persist for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: All local variables go out of scope when the function containing them returns, so pointers to all types of local data become invalid.  If your returned pointers seemed to work for some types but not others, this was because of luck, not anything defined.

Comment: Programming is not an experimental science.  "Try it and see" is a popular practice and (not always advisedly) a popular pedagogical technique, but it's quite easy to draw wildly inaccurate results from it.

Comment: I'm not necessarily trying to experiment. I just ran into it when forgetting to make the struct static, which made me wonder why I was able to still access it despite it not being static. I thought the explanation would be something regarding structs having a certain property  regarding how they're stored.

Comment: @user3386109: If you define an object with `static` inside a function, its scope is local (block scope), but it does not cease to exist when the function returns. So the statement “Officially, local variables cease to exist as soon as the function returns” is not correct. The C standard does not use “variables” or “local variables” to define these concepts, so you should avoid using them because they convey the rules incorrectly.

Comment: @SteveSummit: Local variables do not go out of scope when the function containing them returns because *scope* is a set of locations in source code, not times in program execution. Scope is the wrong concept; it is defined behavior in appropriate circumstances for code to access objects that are not in scope of that code. Lifetime and storage duration are the applicable concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observations about data in a two-dimensional array of `char` or a `struct` appearing to persist or not after a function returns are the results of happenstance, not behavior defined by the C standard, and you may not rely on them. They were merely artifacts of how your C compiler behaved in particular circumstances. They may change in other circumstances and may not be relied on.

Whenever you provide an object to be used after a function returns (as by returning a pointer to the object), it must not have automatic storage duration. It may have static storage duration, allocated storage duration, or thread storage duration.

First, let us clarify some terminology. This is important for understand the concepts. The C standard does not use the term “global variables”. It generally does not use “variable” to describe object and does not use “global” for them at all. What you think of as a variable is, in the C standard, an *identifier* and an *object*. The identifier is the name of the object, and the object is a region of data storage that can represent values.

Whether the C standard guarantees an object can be used at a certain time depends on the object’s *lifetime*. Lifetime is **when** during program execution the object **exists** in the C model of computing. Lifetime is determined in part by its *storage duration*. The storage duration depends on how and where the object was defined or created.

Lifetime is also affected by the *scope* of an object’s identifier. Scope is **where** in the source code an identifier is **visible** (can be used). There are relationships between scope and lifetime, but they are distinctly different things.

There are four storage durations (and a special temporary storage duration, which I will not discuss here):

- If an identifier is declared with `_Thread_local`, its object has thread storage duration. Its lifetime starts when the thread is created and ends when execution of the thread ends. So it can be used after a function returns as long as its thread is still executing.
- Otherwise, if an identifier is declared with `static` or with `extern` or outside of any block or list of function parameters (effectively outside of any function), its object has static storage duration. It exists for the entire execution of the program, so it can be used any time during execution.
- Otherwise, for any identifier for an object (rather than a type definition, function, or such), its object has automatic storage duration. It is associated with the statement block it is declared in. (A block is a sequence of statements inside braces, `{ ... }`. This can be the main block that defines a function or a block nested within it.) Its lifetime ends when execution of the associated block ends. The C standard makes no guarantee about what happens when you attempt to use an automatic object after execution of its block ends.

Note that when a function calls a subroutine, execution of the function, including the blocks within it, is *suspended* temporarily, but it is not ended. (Execution *ends* when the function returns, or special routines like `abort`, `exit`, or `longjmp` are called.) This means that the object still exists while the subroutines are executing. This is true even though the source code in the subroutines has a different scope than the calling function.

Because of the above, statements that say you cannot use objects outside of their scope are false. **Scope is not the determining factor in whether an object may be accessed. Lifetime is.**

For the fourth storage duration:

- Objects with allocated storage duration are created by `malloc`, `calloc`, `realloc`, and `aligned_alloc` and do not have names (identifiers). An allocated objects extends from when it is allocated to when it is deallocated. So, if a function allocates an object and returns a pointer to it, that pointer may be used to access the object until the object is deallocated.